# WF4 is it possible to create a designer for a composite activity?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I know how to hook up a designer activity to a NativeActivity or CodeActivity with the Designer attribute on the class. Like so:

```
[Designer(typeof(ParallelActivityDesigner))]
```

I would like to also hookup a designer to a composite activity (composed of some activities in only a xaml file), is that possible at all?

Comment: After some more research I believe it can't be done. But I also got an idea for a workaround. The idea is to create a NativeActivity and give this native activity the following code in the execute method: protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context) { MyComposoteActivity act = new MyCompositeActivity(); context.ScheduleActivity(act); } And set the designer on this activity. But i'm not sure if this is the way to go, and if all goes well if the wf is persisted. Anybody done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three known ways so far:

1. Have a code-beside .xaml.cs file, and use [DesignerAttribute], like in your question
2. [DesignerAttribute] by editing the XAML file manually
3. Using metadata registration to register custom attributes at design time, easiest in a rehosted scenario, but possible using a .Design.dll inside VS also.

(Ref [Workflow Beta2 forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/e3f21827-7d79-4f7f-a883-b689014959db) for details of the first 2)

Comment: Haven't tried it but I guess 2. is the answer.
<x:ClassAttributes> <sc:DesignerAttribute> <x:Arguments> <x:Type Type="local:MyActivityDesigner" /> </x:Arguments> </sc:DesignerAttribute> </x:ClassAttributes>

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do, check out the SDK sample for creating custom designers with either the WorkflowItemPresenter or the WorkflowItemsPresenter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.workflowitempresenter.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759032.aspx

--matt

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly have this figured out myself. It should be possible but I haven't figured out the exact format the designer needs to be. The best place for info is Matt Winkler (PM on the team working on the designer) at http://blogs.msdn.com/mwinkle